# Non-Homogeneous Differential Equation with Dirac Delta

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$ u^{\prime \prime} = -\frac{F}{EA}\delta(x-L) $$

subjected to the boundary conditions:

$$ u(0) = 0 \qquad \frac{du}{dx} \biggr\vert_{(x=L)}  = 0  $$

I use the following famaous identity:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x-x_i)dx = f(x_i)$$

Hence, first integration gives:

$$ u^\prime (x) - u^\prime (0) = -\int_0^L \frac{F}{EA}\delta(x-L) dx $$

Then,

$$ u(x) - u(0) - u^\prime (0) x = -\int_0^L \int_0^L \frac{F}{EA}\delta(x-L) dx dx$$

Applying the boundary conditions:

$$ u^\prime (L) - u^\prime(0) = -\frac{F}{EA} $$

gives

$$ u^\prime(0) = \frac{F}{EA} $$

Substituting into the equation gives the total solution:

$$ u(x)  -\frac{F}{EA} x = -\int_0^L \int_0^L \frac{F}{EA}\delta(x-L) dx dx $$

which gives at

$$ u(L) = 0 $$

Yet, I know that this is certainly not the solution. I also encounter same difficulty when the domain of integration is $ (0,L) $ but the Dirac Delta is at somewhere between, say, $ \delta(x-0.5L) $. What part do I miss here, can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: $\delta(x)$ is the derivative of $1_{x > 0}$. Your equation is $u''(x) = a \delta(x-L)$ which means $u'(x) = a 1_{x > L} + b, u(x) = a (x-L) 1_{x > L} + bx+c$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I use the identity given. Why it is not giving same result as the one you write?

Comment: The identity is simply wrong. You can not integrate the $\delta$ Distribution like that because it is not an $L^2$ function. It is often found in physics textbooks but has to be treated with extreme caution.

Comment: Come on I have just set $a = -\frac{F}{EA}$. Assume $L > 0$ then $\int_0^x \delta(y-L)dy = 1_{x > L}$ and integrating again gives $(x-L) 1_{x > L}$. In general if $T$ is a compactly supported distribution then its primitive $S(x)=\int_0^x T(y)dy$ is well-defined and $T = S'$, studying such things is the point of distribution theory.

Comment: Thank you for answers. If the identity is wrong, why are we using it in computational mechanics? This identity is widely used. I am confused.

Comment: Its hard to answer that in a comment: In essence distributions are a generalisation of functions (sort of). The natural way how distributions works is they act on a test function. If you have a Distribution that "is" a function this coincides with the integral of the product of the distribution with the test function. That's why the integral notation is widely used. For details you might wanna read up on distributions.

Comment: So I conclude that instead of using integral property, step function must be used as given by @reuns

Comment: The condition $\frac{du}{dx} \biggr\vert_{(x=L)}  = 0$ is not compatible with the differential equation which requires $\frac{du}{dx}$ to be discontinuous at $x=L$. Is it supposed that this boundary condition should refer to the positive side of $x=L$, i.e. $\frac{du}{dx} = 0$ for $x>L$?

Comment: You comment makes sense, yet my physical domain is $(0,L)$, hence $L^+$ is not concerned. Just the value at $x=L$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the boundary condition $u'(L) = 0$ should be $u'(L+) = 0$.

Integrating the equation:
$$\begin{align}
u'' &= -\frac{F}{EA} \delta(x-L), \\
u' &= -\frac{F}{EA} H(x-L) + A, \\
u &= -\frac{F}{EA} (x-L) \, H(x-L) + Ax + B,
\end{align}$$

Using boundary conditions:
$$
0 = u(0) = -\frac{F}{EA} (0-L) \, H(0-L) + A \cdot 0 + B = B, \\
0 = u'(L+) = -\frac{F}{EA} H((L+)-L) + A = -\frac{F}{EA} + A,
$$
i.e.
$$A = \frac{F}{EA}, \quad B = 0.$$

Thus,
$$
u(x) 
= -\frac{F}{EA} (x-L) \, H(x-L) + \frac{F}{EA}x
= \frac{F}{EA} \left( x - (x-L) \, H(x-L) \right)
= \begin{cases}
\frac{F}{EA} x, & (x \leq L) \\
\frac{F}{EA} L, & (x \geq L)
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanatory answer. I understand that my main mistake was to use integral identity involving Dirac Delta, which turns out to be inconsistent mathematically as mentioned in other comments.